# Security.Cryptography.Debug not throwing correct exception

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

I'm trying to debug a crypto function, using the microsoft [Security.Cryptography.Debug.dll](http://clrsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Security.Cryptography.Debug.dll&referringTitle=Home)

I have a reference to the 3 Dlls in the download in my project. My encryption function populates a `SymmetricEncryptionState` object as expected, but my decryption function throws a `CryptographicException` instead of the `CryptographicDiagnosticException` I'm expecting.

```
SymmetricEncryptionState encryptionState = null; //set by encrypt function

public MemoryStream DecryptFileStream(byte[] cypherStream, string password, string salt)
{
    var output = new MemoryStream();

    using (SymmetricAlgorithm AESProvider = new AesManaged().EnableDecryptionVerification(encryptionState))
    {
        var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt));

        AESProvider.KeySize = 256;
        AESProvider.BlockSize = 128;
        AESProvider.Key = key.GetBytes(AESProvider.KeySize / 8);
        AESProvider.IV = key.GetBytes(AESProvider.BlockSize / 8);

        try
        {
        CryptoStream plainTextStream = new CryptoStream(output, AESProvider.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[cypherStream.Length];

        plainTextStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        plainTextStream.FlushFinalBlock(); // this line throws the wrong exception type
        }

        catch (CryptographicDiagnosticException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    return output;
}
```

I'm getting a 'Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.' error on the `FlushFinalBlock()` call.

If it helps, my project is targeting .net 4.5

Does anyone have any ideas on this one?

Comment: Why are you using `SymmetricEncryptionState` in the first place? Why not store the ciphertext as just bytes? " A SymmetricEncryptionState object is an opaque object that contains information about the various parameters used to encrypt some data. This object contains sensitive information, such as the key used for encryption, and as such should not be used in shipping code. Instead, it should only be used while diagnosing problems with encryption code." Source Microsoft.

Comment: For debugging... Perhaps I wasn't clear. The encrypt function is returning a byte array. It also has the enable logging extension populating the symmetricEncryptionState object

Comment: OK, understood. How did you generate the salt string? It's pretty likely that that is the culprit.

Comment: I'll post the code when I get home from work, it's a random string that is passed from the calling class into encrypt and decrypt